# Select rows for the given time interval

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am facing an issue with selecting items within a given time interval.
To illustrate the problem let us consider the table `Orders` with following fields:

```
- id
- order_date
- order_time
- details
```

etc.

I have order_date in MJD format and order_time is in seconds.
Eg., 
order_date = 57281 (in MJD) // 16-Sep-2015
order_time = 32400 (in seconds) // 9:00AM

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT Orders.id, Orders.order_date date, 
Orders.order_time time FROM Orders 
WHERE Orders.date<=endDate and Orders.order_time < endTime)
WHERE date>=startDate and time > startTime
```

This doesn't seem to return proper values since not able associate following time check only when date is start date.

```
WHERE date>=startDate and time > startTime
```

What could be missing here? Are there any other simple ways of handling this kind of queries? Please suggest.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Dates don't have any "format" in a SQL database, the format is only applied when you _display_ them.

Comment: I am using SQLite database used to store data in small devices... currently date and time are stored with type INTEGER and no particular format. INTEGER date represents MJD date. INTEGER time represents corresponding number seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert date and time to a combined datetime value and then use only one condition, you can use `WHERE dateTime BETWEEN startDateTime AND endDateTime`.

The problem is that you filter already the records using first condition and this leaves you for the second condition only datetimes that have time e.g. `<9:00AM`.

Comparing date and time separately when you look for datetime values within an interval is misleading because when the interval is `'2015-09-16 12:00:00' - '2015-09-17 12:00:00'` you miss values like `'2015-09-16 13:00:00'`, `'2015-09-16 14:00:00'` etc. because they have higher time value than `endTime= '12:00:00'`.

Comment: Changed table to have single field representing date and time. Now query is fairly simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may Also try this one, It worked for me.

```
Where 
   DATE(date) >= startDate
   AND DATE(time) >= StartTime
```

OrElse You may Use

```
Where
    datetime(StartDate) <= now()
```

For more  advanced help please check [SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp)